# extract a single column

Tags: r, list

I have a list of 701 given `csv` files. Each one has the same number of columns (7) but different number of rows (between 25000 and 28000).

Here is an extract of the first file:

```
Date,Week,Week Day,Hour,Price,Volume,Sale/Purchase
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-3000.00,17416,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-1001.10,17427,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-1000.00,18055,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-500.10,18057,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-500.00,18064,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-400.10,18066,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-400.00,18066,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-300.10,18068,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-300.00,18118,Sell
```

I made a nonlinear regression of the supply curve of the ninth hour for the year 2012. The datas for 2012 are in 290. to 654. csv files.

```
allenamen <- dir(pattern="*.csv")
alledat <- lapply(allenamen, read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
h <- list()
for(i in 290:654) {
g <- function(a, b, c, d, p) {a*atan(b*p+c)+d}
f <- nlsLM(Volume ~ g(a,b,c,d,Price), data=subset(alledat[[i-289]], (Hour==9) & (Sale.Purchase == "Sell") & (!Price %in% as.character(-50:150))), start = list(a=4000, b=0.1, c=-5, d=32000))
h[[i-289]] <- coef(f)
}
```

This works and I get the coefficients a, b, c and d for every day in 2012.

This is the `head(h)`:

```
[[1]]
        a             b             c             d 
2.513378e+03  4.668218e-02 -3.181322e+00  2.637142e+04 

[[2]]
        a             b             c             d 
2.803172e+03  6.696201e-02 -4.576432e+00  2.574454e+04 

[[3]]
        a             b             c             d 
 3.298991e+03  5.817949e-02 -3.425728e+00  2.393888e+04 

[[4]]
        a             b             c             d 
 2.150487e+03  3.810406e-02 -2.658772e+00  2.675609e+04 

[[5]]
        a             b             c             d 
2.326199e+03  3.044967e-02 -1.780965e+00  2.604374e+04 

[[6]]
        a             b             c             d 
2934.0193270     0.0302937    -1.9912913 26283.0300823
```

And this is `dput(head(h))`:

```
list(structure(c(2513.37818972349, 0.0466821822063123, -3.18132213466142, 
26371.4241646124), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d")), structure(c(2803.17230054557, 
0.0669620116294894, -4.57643230249848, 25744.5376725213), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d")), structure(c(3298.99066895304, 0.0581794881246528, 
-3.42572804902504, 23938.8754575156), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d")), structure(c(2150.48734655237, 0.0381040636898022, -2.65877160023262, 
26756.0907073567), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d")), structure(c(2326.19873555633, 
0.0304496684589379, -1.7809654498454, 26043.735374657), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d")), structure(c(2934.01932702805, 0.0302937043170001, 
-1.99129130343521, 26283.0300823458), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d")))
```

Now I am trying to get just a column with `h$a` but I get NULL. How can I get just the a column?

In addition to this I want to plot the single coefficients and `Date`. I tried this code:

```
koeffreihe <- function(x) {
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")    
df <- data.frame()  
for(i in 1:length(files)){
xx <- read.csv(as.character(files[i]))    
xx <- subset(xx, Sale.Purchase == "Sell" & Hour == 3)
df <- rbind(df, xx)
g <- function(a, b, c, d, p) {a*atan(b*p+c)+d}
f <- nlsLM(Volume ~ g(a,b,c,d,Price), data=subset(alledat[[i]], (Hour==9) & (Sale.Purchase == "Sell") & (!Price %in% as.character(-50:150))), start = list(a=4000, b=0.1, c=-5, d=32000))
h[[i]] <- coef(f)  
}
df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format="%d/%m/%Y")
plot(h$x ~ Date, df, xlim = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-12-31")))
}

koeffreihe(a)
```

But I get this error:

```
invalid type (NULL) for variable 'h$x'
```

So the problem is that `h$a` is NULL. If someone can fix this problem I guess the code will work too.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, h)$a`.

Comment: @roland I tried j <- do.call(rbind,h) and then j$a but I get this error: error in j$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. class(j$a) is a matrix. I changed the class to data.frame and list but then I get NULL.

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind.data.frame, h)$a`. If you provided a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059), I could help you better.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it will help understanding my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First transform your list into a data.frame:

```
h.df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, h), names(h[[1]]))
#         a          b         c        d
#1 2513.378 0.04668218 -3.181322 26371.42
#2 2803.172 0.06696201 -4.576432 25744.54
#3 3298.991 0.05817949 -3.425728 23938.88
#4 2150.487 0.03810406 -2.658772 26756.09
#5 2326.199 0.03044967 -1.780965 26043.74
#6 2934.019 0.03029370 -1.991291 26283.03
```

Then you can extract variables easily:

```
h.df$a
#[1] 2513.378 2803.172 3298.991 2150.487 2326.199 2934.019
```

Alternatively you can iterate over the list to extract the variable:

```
sapply(h, "[", "a")
#       a        a        a        a        a        a 
#2513.378 2803.172 3298.991 2150.487 2326.199 2934.019
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first problem is solved. But I get still an error in my my plot function "koeffreihe". I edited my entrance post. Do you have an idea for it?

Comment: If your problem is solved now you should consider accepting and upvoting an answer. I've reverted your edit. If you have a new question, ask a new question. However, you should first try to debug your code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In this line, although `x` is a variable, `h$x` is looking for a column named `x` in `h`:

```
plot(h$x ~ Date, df, xlim = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-12-31")))
```

You probably want `h[[x]]` instead.

From `?'[['`:

```
x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]].
```

That is, you are looking for a column literally named `x`.

Comment: I tried h[[x]] in the plot line but I get this: error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : argument 'x' is missing with no default. I also tried it without the variable x and tried h[[a]] and h$a but R does not find a in both cases.